# Can anyone help me by getting The plain text from a div placed in an html file

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

i am a facing an error while using php simple html dom . I am working on my school project to get the plain text from a following div which is situated in an html file

```
<div class="product-detail__TextPrice-sc-1k47nh4-0 hECROB d-flex align-items-center  justify-content-md-start">
  <div class="mb-0 weight-bold price">
    ₹<!-- --> <!-- -->126.00
  </div>
  <div class="mrp ml-md-4 ml-lg-2 pd-mrp">
    ₹ 150.00
  </div>
  <div class=" w-50 margin-text ml-md-4 ml-lg-2">
    <span class="main-slab main-slab-detail">
      1+pc
    </span>
    Margin ₹ 24.00 | 16.00%
  </div>
</div>
```

This div is present in an html file and we have got only the url to file and we have to first bring the mrp cost of item in div class `mrp ml-md-4 ml-lg-2 pd-mrp` and cost from class
`mb-0 weight-bold price`
I was using php simple html dom to do the process but i am getting a huge array and I can't figure out what to do now . Can anyone please guide me out ,. The code which i am using is below

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php'); 

$cl=file_get_contents($url);

$html=new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($cl);
$ret = $html->find('div[class=mrp ml-md-4 ml-lg-2 pd-mrp]');

var_dump($ret);

?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi ! Please try `$html->find("div.mrp.ml-md-4.ml-lg-2.pd-mrp")` ie the div which matches all the classes and let us know what you get :)

Comment: Sir when i perform the same and do a var_dump it gives array(0) { }.

Answer (score 0):

Try this script.

Because `$html->find('div.pd-mrp')` return multiple elements.

```
$html=new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($cl);

foreach($html->find('div.pd-mrp') as $elements) {
    echo $elements->plaintext;
    break;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Sir now it's a blank page  . I used both your's method as well as this by modifying your's one but still both shows sane blank page              ```foreach($html->find('div[class=mrp ml-md-4 ml-lg-2 pd-mrp]') as $elements) {
    echo $elements->plaintext;
    break;
}```.  Sir if you say i can share the website as well

Comment: its working for me. Please check screenshot in my answer section

Comment: please share the website

Comment: Sir here is the code which isn't working for me
```
<?php

include('simple_html_dom.php'); 

$cl = file_get_contents("https://www.lotswholesale.com/product/104461622/1002")

$html=new simple_html_dom();

$html->load($cl);

$ret = $html->find("div.mrp.ml-md-4.ml-lg-2.pd-mrp",0)->plaintext;

print_r($ret);

?>```

Comment: The website is https://www.lotswholesale.com/product/104461622/1002. This website is just a demo site , which i randomly selected for my project .

Comment: Sir one of the major issue might be that you are just using the division code which i manually took out from the site but i have to create a code which would do the same and then perform the above things on it And thanks for responding .

Comment: Sir do you have any workaround as i have to submit tge same by tomorrow as a project .

Comment: @PIYUSHADLAKHA,  it is fixed?

Comment: Not yet sir but i just asked my teacher to assign new site and i have submitted the project but still this remains a mystery

Comment: Okay. assigned new site or working with old website?

Comment: Ya sir sorry for late reply but i have been assigned a new site.  But i am still trying to solve out this puzzle out of curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

**Final answer** :

The target value is a price on a product page. This value is not served at first call, so simple_html_dom can't access it. The workaround would be to **scrape** the frontend page in a browser extension for example, and to get the value via javascript. This way, you could get your value and process it or send it back to php, if you need.

**First answer** :

I've made a text text on my server :

```
<?php

include('simple_html_dom.php'); 

$cl = <<< TEST
<div class="product-detail__TextPrice-sc-1k47nh4-0 hECROB d-flex align-items-center  justify-content-md-start">
  <div class="mb-0 weight-bold price">
    ₹<!-- --> <!-- -->126.00
  </div>
  <div class="mrp ml-md-4 ml-lg-2 pd-mrp">
    ₹ 150.00
  </div>
  <div class=" w-50 margin-text ml-md-4 ml-lg-2">
    <span class="main-slab main-slab-detail">
      1+pc
    </span>
    Margin ₹ 24.00 | 16.00%
  </div>
</div>
TEST;

$html=new simple_html_dom();

$html->load($cl);

$ret = $html->find("div.mrp.ml-md-4.ml-lg-2.pd-mrp",0)->plaintext;

print_r($ret);

?>
```

it outputs :

```
₹ 150.00
```

Comment: Sir one of the major issue might be that you are just using the division code which i manually took out from the site but i have to create a code which would do the same and then perform the above things on it and thanks for responding

Comment: Yes indeed ! ;)

Comment: So can you help me out of it , the website is https://www.lotswholesale.com/product/104461622/1002

Comment: When I grab the page via `file_get_contents` and `echo` it the pseudo page I view does not contain the div you are look for. It must appear after the page is loaded and interpreted via the browser itself. It makes sense, the actual price is not a fixed value on the page, but a value requested by the client in a second time :)

Comment: So sir any workaround for the same

Comment: The workaround would be to scrap the frontend page in a `browser extension` for example, and to get the value via javascript. This way, you could get your value and process it or send it back to php, if you need.

Comment: Sir i am not well with js so can you please help me further , i just require the current price & the mrp . Sorry for disturbing you again and again but i have to submit it to school by Tomorrow and i cannot learn js in a night.

Comment: Sorry if my answer generates more problems than it resolves :( Maybe somebody else is going to provide a easier one :)